# Probability of a home run given pitcher and hitter quality

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble thinking through a probability question. If batter A has a 6.12% chance of hitting a home run against a league average pitcher, pitcher B has a 3.14% chance of giving up a home run against a league average hitter, and the average across the league is that a home run is hit in 2.86% of all plate appearance, what is the probability that batter A hits a home run off of pitcher B?

Intuitively I believe it should be slightly higher than 6.12%. The batter has that probability against a league average pitcher and the pitcher gives up home runs slightly more than league average. Is there a simple formula or model for solving these types of problems or will a logistic regression on a large set of plate appearances be necessary to estimate the probabilities?

I highly appreciate any help you can provide.

This is part of a larger project to simulate plate appearances in baseball games (and eventually entire baseball games.) I'm trying to estimate the probability of four possible outcomes, HR, K, BB, or ball-in-play. The best I've been able to come up with right now is to say the pitcher is 10.03% more likely than league average to give up a home run, and the batter is 114.09% more likely than league average to hit a home run. Then multiply, (1+.1003)*1.1409=1.2553. Meaning in this plate appearance, a home run is 125.53% more likely than league average. The league average being 2.86% means a home run has a probability of 6.45%, .0286*(1+1.2553)=.0645. The problem now, is that if I repeat this method for the other three outcomes, I get a total probability of 101.72%. I can work around this by scaling, giving a home run probability of 6.34%, (1/1.0172)*.0645. This fits my intuition of "slightly higher than 6.12%" but honestly feels a bit *too* high. Just wondering if anyone has a better solution out there or a good feel for these types of probabilities. Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to model the situation (and there is no unique way to do that).  Having attached some metric to both positions, you can set probability distribution for both.  You shouldn't expect this to be very good...there are lots of significant side parameters (handedness of the players, the score, any runners on base, and so on).

Comment: A similar estimate for game win probability is provided by $P(A \text{ wins}) = \frac{p_A(1-p_B)}{p_A(1-p_B)+p_B(1-p_A)}$, if $p_A$ and $p_B$ are the winning probabilities of $A$ and $B$, respectively, against the league average. In that case, though, the analysis is simplified by the league average winning probability being $0.500$, of course. Keep in mind that all such estimates are heuristics. They cannot generally be rigorously justified.

Comment: I wrote an answer on the above heuristic for game-win probability on a recent question. In it, I put a [link](https://sabr.org/journal/article/probabilities-of-victory-in-head-to-head-team-matchups/) to a paper that goes into the motivation and some empirical evidence. Maybe take a look at that and see if you can adapt it to your problem.

Comment: For more than 90% of humankind your text isn't understandable (for example what is a "league average pitcher"?), but, please, at least say at the beginning that your issue is about **baseball**...

Comment: @BrianTung I tried that formula originally, and that gave me a probability of about 67%. I believe the issue is with this not being a binary outcome, there are four possible outcomes in any given plate appearance (the way I'm modeling it at this step)

Comment: @JeanMarie my apologies, I thought including home run in the title made it clear. Thanks for the feedback but I guess I'm targeting the 10% of people who do understand it anyway...

Comment: Thanks for the humorous answer...

Comment: @rwgreber3: I don't think that you can have applied it the expected way. The expected way gives an answer that is too low, not too high.

Comment: @BrianTung For the numerator I have .0612*(1-.0314)=.0593 and for the denominator I have .0612*(1-.0314)+.0314*(1-.0612)=.0888. Giving .0593/.0888=.6675. Do you have something different or am I overlooking something?

Comment: You "should" be adding consistent probabilities: the probability that the batter hits a home run times the probability that the pitcher gives one up (both of those are small); then the probability that the batter fails to hit a home run times the probability doesn't give one up (both of those are large). But this gives an answer that is too small, about $0.002$ (at least an order of magnitude too small). The league average needs to be taken into account, obviously, but I don't know exactly how.

Comment: @BrianTung ah got it, that makes sense. Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Note that when you use the `*` character in the question text, sometimes it just sets part of the question in italics instead of showing the '*' that you intended. We have a better way to show math formulas here; see http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation. You can write a nice multiplication symbol ($\times$) using the code `\times` inside a MathJax formula.

Comment: @DavidK appreciate the feedback. I was wondering why part of my question was in italics

Answer (score 1):

> what is the probability that batter A hits a home run off of pitcher B?

This is actually two questions:

- (1) Can you use the information given to mathematically compute the probability?
- (2) Can you use intuition to estimate the probability?  If so, how close can you come.

---

For (1), the answer is **no**.

Formally, first consider [Bayes Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

Let $E_1$ be the event that batter-A hits a home-run. 
Let $E_2$ be the event that the pitcher has the approximate skill of pitcher-B.

Let $p(R|S)$ denote the probability of event $R$ occurring, given that event $S$ has occurred.

Let $p(R,S)$ denote the probability of events $R$ and $S$ both occurring.

Your question is equivalent to asking for

$$p(E_1|E_2) = \frac{p(E_1,E_2)}{p(E_2)}. \tag1 $$

In (1) above, the LHS is unknown, and in the fraction on the RHS, the numerator is unknown.  In the fraction on the RHS, the denominator could be determined, but given that the numerator is unknown, this won't solve the problem.

Further, the **mirror** approach described below, will also fail, for the same reason.

That is, you could let

$E_3$ denote the event that Pitcher-B gives up a home-run 
$E_4$ denote the event that the batter has the approximate skill of batter-A.

Then, you have that

$$p(E_3|E_4) = \frac{p(E_3,E_4)}{p(E_4)}. \tag2 $$

Here, the analysis parallels the analysis of (1), detailed above.

---

For question (2) : 
This is an extraordinarily complicated question that is attacked by professional sports-bettors and professional bookmakers, on a daily basis.  Often, *rookie* sports-bettors will attempt a mathermatical approach.  Professional sports bettors will typically regard such a mathematical approach as *better than nothing, but inferior to personal scrutiny*.

As the OP (i.e. original poster) indicated, you would expect that batter-A will have a higher probability of hitting a home-run than normal, because he is facing a (moderately) sub-standard pitcher.  In fact, although this will **usually** be an accurate inference, it **is not necessarily true**.

For example, suppose that most batters do well against pitches above the waist, and that batter-A does better with pitches at the knees.  Further assume that pitcher-B has *trouble keeping the pitch low*.  So pitcher-B is substandard against most hitters because they excel at pitches in the upper part of the strike zone.

Further, it is not unrealistic that batter-A is better than league average hitting home-runs, despite his preference for pitches lower in the strike zone.  So, in the (**very specific**) match-up of batter-A and pitcher-B, batter-A's probability of hitting a home-run could actually **decrease**.

---

Going further, once you reach the level of *considering the individual match-up* (i.e. either batter-A against pitcher-B, or team-1 against team-2), you have a further level of complication.

The (euphemistic) *right-line* is totally dependent on the level of information available.  For example, a professional bookmaker, going by the wisdom of years of successfully analyzing match-ups, might estimate that the correct payoff for an upcoming Home-Team-A vs Visitor-Team-B is

$$-1.30 ~: ~\text{represents that probability of Team-A winning is} ~\frac{13}{23}.$$

So, the bookmaker makes the spread

$$-1.40 ~::~ + 1.25,$$

which signifies that you have to put up $\$140$ on Team-A to win $\$100$, and (alternatively) put up $\$100$ on Team-B to win $\$125$.

Against the typical sports bettor, whose *information* is no better than the bookmaker's information, it is reasonable to regard $-1.30$ as the **right line**.

However, what about the sports bettor with superior information, that might know (for example) that one of the following occurred:

- The airplane carrying team-B to the game was three hours late, so the Team-B players won't be as well rested as normal.
- The starting pitcher for team-A, while warming up, 10 minutes before the game, has demonstrated a *hitch* in his windup.  It could take a couple of days for him to regain his coordination.  Meanwhile, the sports bettor that happens to be watching the warmups has better information than the bookmaker.

The above considerations will often indicate that for the superior knowledge, the *right-line* might be as high as $-200$, or as low as $-120$ going the other way (i.e. that the road team might have a $\dfrac{6}{11}$ probability of winning the game).

Answer (score -1):

https://tht.fangraphs.com/a-short-digression-into-log5/

[Baseball, batting average, and probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513627/baseball-batting-average-and-probability?rq=1)

I believe I found a satisfactory answer to this question from the above links. Shout out Michael Lugo for his comment and thanks everyone for your help.

I'm still open to better ways of doing it if there's anyone out there with an idea.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).